# Changing Annotation value via Reflection does not work JDK17

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, reflection, annotations

I have spring boot application with some controllers.

All the controllers have @RequestMapping annotation with a path/value attribute. I would like to change the value of this attribute at runtime by hooking into the bean lifecycle.

I am using BeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization() to accomplish this and below is the reflection code that I use:

```
public class RequestMappingProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor
{
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException
    {
        RequestMapping requestMapping = bean.getClass().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);

        System.out.println("OldAnnotation Value " + requestMapping.value()[0]);

        Map<String, Object> attributes = AnnotationUtils.getAnnotationAttributes(requestMapping);
        String[] values = (String[]) attributes.get("path");
        var newValue = getNewPath(path);

        Object handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);
        Field f;
        try
        {
            f = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, Object> memberValues;
        try
        {
            memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) f.get(handler);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        Object oldValue = memberValues.get(key);
        if (oldValue == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        memberValues.put(key, newValue);
        memberValues.put("path", newValue);
        
        System.out.println("New Annotation Value " + requestMapping.value()[0]);
}
```

The things is that I do see it printing the updated values on console, but when I check the actual endpoint in postman or browser, still the old path works and not the new one.
JDK 17.

I know that many would suggest to set the prefixed path at API level for all the controllers and all, but in my case, each controller might have a different prefix based upon some annotation. If you have some other suggestions, please suggest.

Comment: So “each controller might have a different prefix based upon some annotation” means, instead of just fixing the annotation in the first place, you added another annotation to tell how to modify the original annotation at runtime?

Comment: Right. But I achieved this by overriding the initialization of handler mappings via WebMvcConfigurer.

Answer (score 0):

To those who are looking to accomplish the same, you can do this by overriding the `WebMvcConfigurer.configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer)` method in your custom configurer and set the prefixes for all the controllers based upon your custom logic using  `configurer.addPathPrefix()`.